StartError (exit code 128) when pod tries to mount configmap that is being changed at same time
This is happening when deploying a pod with argo workflow and there is another job running which is editing the configmap
The workflow failed with following error
StartError (exit code 128):
failed to create containerd task: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error mounting "/var/lib/kubelet/pods/f22aa0b7-afdc-497c-beb3-ccb394e8428d/volume-subpaths/config/wait/9" to rootfs at "/mainctrfs/my.py": mount /var/lib/kubelet/pods/f22aa0b7-afdc-497c-beb3-ccb394e8428d/volume-subpaths/my-py/wait/9:/mainctrfs/my.py (via /proc/self/fd/6), flags: 0x5001, data: context="system_u:object_r:data_t:s0:c923,c1020": no such file or directory: unknown

In fact it would be helpful if someone can point to some good documentation about how kubernetes does locking of resources.
